# Import issue with Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication, import

When I import some data from excel file to a table that is part of a merge replication, the data is imported successfully to the table, but those new records are not synced to subscribers that belong to the merge replication topology!

Is this by default?

Am I missing some configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the Import wizard ( because it is considered like a Bulk Insert or BCP ) is disabling replication triggers on the tables they are loading data to, which prevents Merge Replication from detecting new records.

This article: [Bulk loading data into a merge replicated table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/bulk-loading-data-into-a) explains this with more details.

One workaround is to use the procedure: sp_addtablecontents after importing data to let the merge replication detect the new rows like the following:

```
Exec sp_addtabletocontents @table_name = 'Customers'
```

Comment: I know I am very late to the party but this might still help someone,
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2011/02/09/replicating-data-loaded-with-bcp-or-bulk-insert/